# How to manage order of column in Data Frame based on start of their names in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have sample of Data Frame pandas in Python like below:

```
COL_a | NUM_b | col | NUM_a | COL_b
-----------------------------------
12   | 23     | 8   | 1     | 7
22   | 14     |12   | 2     |13
```

And I would like to manage the order of columns so as to have to have columns starting the same way next to each other.

I need to tell you that in my real Data Frame I have several hundred columns, so easiest way `df[["COL_a", "COL_b", "NUM_a", "NUM_b", "col]]` is not possible because it will not work on huge dataset.

What can I do that in Python Pandas ?

As a result I need like below:

```
COL_a | COL_b | NUM_a | NUM_b | col
-----------------------------------
12   | 7      | 1     | 23    | 8
22   | 13     | 2     | 14    |12
```

In terms of new example:

Current situation (column IDX is index):

```
IDX   | col1 | col2
----- ------------
COL_a | 22   | 11
col11 | 33   | 22
NUM_b | 11   | 33
COL_b | 11   | 44
NUM_a | 24   | 55
```

Expected output:

```
IDX   | col1 | col2
----- ------------
COL_a | 22   | 11
COL_b | 11   | 44
NUM_a | 24   | 55
NUM_b | 11   | 33
col11 | 33   | 22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) on `axis=1` to sort column names lexicographically:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

```
   COL_a  COL_b  NUM_a  NUM_b  col
0     12      7      1     23    8
1     22     13      2     14   12
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'COL_a': [12, 22], 'NUM_b': [23, 14], 'col': [8, 12], 'NUM_a': [1, 2],
    'COL_b': [7, 13]
})
```

---

Related: if using string representations of numeric values like COL_1, COL_2 etc, we can use [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) to ensure natural ordering:

```
import pandas as pd
from natsort import natsort_key

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'COL_1': [12, 22], 'NUM_1': [23, 14],
    'COL_10': [3, 4], 'NUM_10': [6, 8],
    'COL_2': [9, 11], 'NUM_2': [15, 17],
})

print('Initial')
print(df)
print('Without Natsort')
print(df.sort_index(axis=1))
print('With Natsort')
print(df.sort_index(axis=1, key=natsort_key))
```

Output:

```
Initial
   COL_1  NUM_1  COL_10  NUM_10  COL_2  NUM_2
0     12     23       3       6      9     15
1     22     14       4       8     11     17
Without Natsort  # 10 is before 2 (lexicographic)
   COL_1  COL_10  COL_2  NUM_1  NUM_10  NUM_2
0     12       3      9     23       6     15
1     22       4     11     14       8     17
With Natsort  # 10 is _after_ 2 (numeric/natural)
   COL_1  COL_2  COL_10  NUM_1  NUM_2  NUM_10
0     12      9       3     23     15       6
1     22     11       4     14     17       8
```

Comment: ooo nice it works, but could you also present solution if I would like to do the some in terms of index ? so for example I have 4 columns: IDX, col1, col2, col3 and I would like to sort values based on starting element in index ? so I think simmilar like you presented above ? :)

Comment: What do you mean "starting element in the index"? What is the output in this new example?

Comment: Henry, I modified post and I added thing you requested, could you check it ? :)

Comment: remember that IDX is index :)

Comment: Just drop the axis=1. Axis=1 is the columns. So `axis=0` would be the index (which is the default) `df = df.sort_index()` or `df = df.sort_index(key=natsort_key)`

Comment: Perfect! it works! Thank you!, I gave best answer :)